# CF file not found with Apache virtual hosts

Tags: apache, coldfusion, virtualhost

I have Apache 2.2 configured to run with Coldfusion 9.2, both on the same Centos 6.2. The general config of DocumentRoot in Apache is

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

Up until now Apache handed all calls to cfcs and cfms over to Coldfusion. I then created a virtual host

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.123.207:80>
    ServerName myserver.server.private
    ServerAlias www.myserver.server.private
    ServerAlias webmail.myserver.server.private
    ServerAlias admin.myserver.server.private
    DocumentRoot /home/myserver/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/myserver.server.private_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/myserver.server.private_access_log combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/myserver/cgi-bin/
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
    <Directory /home/myserver/public_html>
        Options +Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All                     
        Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/myserver/cgi-bin>
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All     
        Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.myserver.server.private
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://myserver.server.private:20000/ [R]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.myserver.server.private
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://myserver.server.private:10000/ [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

When I open a html file on http://myserver.server.private/hello.html, the correct file within the virtual host document root (/home/myserver/public_html) gets served.

Calling a cfm fails though. Apache passes the request on correctly but then a Coldfusion error message shows up:

```
File not found: /hello.cfm
```

It seems that Coldfusion is getting the file name, prefixes a wrong directory path to it and fails loading it from the disk.

I scanned all Coldfusion files for a wrong document root but could not find anything.

**EDIT**

It turns out that Coldfusion looks into it's own webroot directory at

```
/opt/coldfusion/wwwroot
```

I placed a file with the same name but different content there and that one gets served, although there is a) a virtual host and b) the general DocumentRoot is set to /var/www/html.

Comment: I am not familiar with your setup, Apache and Centos, but even on JRun  and Windows ColdFusion will still look into it's own webroot directory and serve files from that location even if one with the same name exists in the webroot defined on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the coldfusion user (cfusion in my case) needs to be in the group of the virtual host user.

```
usermod -a -G newuser cfusion
```

After a restart of coldfusion, all works.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your resolution.